# How to force TextField to be fully stretched horizontally in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield

I a beginner in iOS programming.

I was following a tutorial, and I had to create TextField as shown in the picture below. what I am trying to do is, to force the width of the TextField to expand when the screen in in Landscape mode. In the tutorial I am following, this step is explained and according to the that tutorial I have to press ctrl and drag the TextField vertically to invoke the AutoLayout engine, I did that but when I rotate the simulator the width doesn't grow.

**image vertically**:

[image]

**image horizontally**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Leading` and `Trailing` space of your `UITextField` to your `view`. See screenshot below:

[image]

You also need to set the vertical constraints (Top/Bottom/Height) otherwise you will receive an error. From my example I set the `Top` spacing and `Height` since UITextField usually have constant heights.

Comment: would you please tell me how can I get that menu? the one which is called Add New Constraints.

Comment: is Constraints designed to designate the dimensions of a view in landscape mode?

Comment: @user2121 Yes, in my example if you rotate the device to landscape, the textfield will stretch its width until 16 pts space constraints on both sides is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

for the horizontal layout you have to...

1. ctrl drag from the textfield to the left of it and add a leading constraint to its superview
2. ctrl drag from the textfield to the right of it and add a trailing constraint to its superview

and - if you didn't already do that - you also have to ctrl drag from the textfield to the top of it and add a top constraint (to the top layout guide for example) to set its vertical position